# onfocus even is not working for apex:inputText. Any one could you please provide an example

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to use both onfocus and onchange event on salesforce `apex:inputTex`t tag. Here, onfocus is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testFocus()
        {
            alert('Hi');
        };

</script>

<apex:inputText value="{!testDesc}" onchange="setTabUnsavedChangesOnForm();return false" maxlength="18" onfocus="testFocus();return false" id="description">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testFocus()
        {
            alert('Hi');
        }

</script>

<apex:inputText value="{!testDesc}" onchange="setTabUnsavedChangesOnForm();return false" maxlength="18" onfocus="testFocus();return false" id="description">
```

Remove extra semicolon from method end.

Comment: It is working in normal mode, but not working in console view, have you any idea!

Comment: @VenkataRaja did you get any error in console mode or disable anything.

Comment: I didn't disabled anything, just I am using same page without doing any changes.

Comment: Hi Thank you!, its working now. Other team member did modification without my permission.

Comment: @VenkataRaja goo dto knwo it is working now. Now you can close this question.